# How to change a value inside a mothod using AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm kinda green to AspectJ and I have been trying to mod some game written in Java (Space Haven). To achieve what I want I must change a int variable.

Here's the code snippet:

```
private void createClaimButton() {
  //some code here
        public void clicked() {
          boolean canClaim = false;
          int total = 8; <- I want to change this value
          } 
        //some code here
```

I've tried this:

```
@Aspect
public abstract class moreShipPointAspect {
@Pointcut("within(public void fi.bugbyte.spacehaven.GUI.SelectedElements.createClaimButton().clicked())")
public abstract void clicked();

@Around("clicked()")
public void replaceValue(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
    args[1] = 128;
    pjp.proceed(args);
    }
}
```

But upon compiling the mod I get this error:

`[ERROR]C:\Users\user\SpaceHavenModTemplate\src\main\java\com\zemogiter\MoreShipPoints\moreShipPointAspect.java:10:0::0 Syntax error on token "within(public void fi.bugbyte.spacehaven.GUI.SelectedElements.createClaimButton().clicked())", ")" expected`

From what I've read, there seem to be something fron with my pointcut and I tried `call`,`execution` and `within` to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: In this particular example, what is contained in the first "some code here" block? Like this, I just see a method inside a method, which is not even valid Java syntax, unless the hidden block contains some kind of anonymous class declaration. But nobody can know that without a magical crystal globe.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: What you want is impossible with AspectJ. Local variables cannot be manipulated, only things like

- field read/write access,
- method/constructor calls and their input parameters and/or results.

There are a few other things you can do, but I am not listing them here.

The reason you get a syntax error is that AspectJ does not like your fantasy syntax. `within` is for types, not methods. For method interception, you have other pointcut types such as `call` and `execution`. Furthermore, you cannot, like in source, code, just chain method calls like `.createClaimButton().clicked()`. In byte code, these are two separate method calls.

You also cannot use `pjp.getArgs()` to get a local *variable value*, because, like the method name implies, it is meant to give you the *method arguments*.

I recommend to learn AspectJ basics. Start from existing examples and try to understand them. Do not just invent use cases and syntax. That does not help you much.